# schema.org markup for product with different prices

Tags: schema.org

is there a way to specify something like "Price Starts at" in schema.org markup for a product with with different prices? (price change based on the options selected)

Answer (score 1):

To get even more specific with your pricing markup, you also might want to consider GoodRelations.  http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Cookbook/Pricing

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AggregateOffer](http://schema.org/AggregateOffer)

It has [lowPrice](http://schema.org/lowPrice) property to mark the lowest price.

Comment: AggregateOffer is meant for when there are multiple sellers on the same product, I didn't see any documentation suggesting a proper markup for a product with different prices (from a single seller)